# jQuery .replaceWith() adds &nbsp;'s to string

Tags: javascript, jquery, replacewith

Im using [imojify](https://github.com/danielthepope/imojify) in a comment system which converts colon-nation emojis to svg images.

The user can edit a comment if hes clicking on it.

To keep the emojis i replace the existing `<span class="emoji emoji-laughing" title=":laughing:"></span>` with the title of the span in this case `:laughing:` and recall the imojify function after the comment was edited so it changes to svg's again.

I noticed a strange behaviour if a emoji is at the end of the comment and you click there and hit backspace to edit it there are several `&nbsp;` added to the string.
Why is this? And how can i remove them.

[image]
This is the created string
`lorem ipsum :grimacing:&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;`

Heres the code (with this example there are only 2  's)
*try to click at the very end of the `p` in my post and hit backspace. There will be 2 `&nbsp;`'s added*

```js
$('.comments').on('mousedown', '.comment p', function(){
  editComment($(this));
});

function editComment(el) {
  $(el).children('span').each(function(){
    var emoji = $(this).attr('title');
    $(this).replaceWith(emoji);
  });
}
```

```css
.comments {
 min-height: 45px;
 width: 100%;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 padding: 0 20px;
}

.comment {
 padding: 7px 10px;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 background: #efefef;
}

.comment p {
 line-height: 30px;
 font-size: 16px;
 padding: 0 10px;
}

.comment p:focus {
 background: #fff;
}

.emoji {
 width: 1.4em;
 height: 1.4em;
 position: relative;
 top: 0.15em;
 display: inline-block;
 background-size: contain;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: 0;
 background-image: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/124740/1f62c.svg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.ice-creme.de/js/imojify.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="comments">
 <div class="comment">
  <p contenteditable="true">
   lorem ipsum 
   <span class="emoji emoji-grimacing" title=":grimacing:"></span>
  </p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide a **runnable** [mcve] that reproduces problem

Comment: will do. Just gonna take a few minutes. Cant implement imojify here

Comment: Probably can if there is a cdn source for that script. Can put any external resources inside a snippet by clicking on `<>` in editor. Or put it in a sandbox like jsfiddle, codepen etc

Comment: It seems like your cursor moves all the way yo the end before it edits the comment. Try and use ```.trim()``` on the comment string before editing/adding the emoji. It should removed all beginning and trailing spaces

Comment: no theres no cdn sadly but i have the snippet now

Comment: Try to rerpoduce your issue on the snippet code you posted.

Comment: @SilverSurfer the issue is there too. "try to click at the very end of the snipped in my post and hit backspace. There will be 2 &nbsp;'s added"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&nbsp` appears because you had set a padding to `p` tag, which is the content editable. To solve this, set padding to 0 and double padding on `.comment` class, from `padding: 7px 10px;` to `padding: 7px 20px;`

```js
$('.comments').on('mousedown', '.comment p', function(){
  editComment($(this));
});

function editComment(el) {
  $(el).children('span').each(function(){
    var emoji = $(this).attr('title');
    $(this).replaceWith(emoji);
  });
}
```

```css
.comments {
 min-height: 45px;
 width: 100%;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 padding: 0 20px;
}

.comment {
 padding: 7px 20px;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 background: #efefef;
}

.comment p {
 line-height: 30px;
 font-size: 16px;
 padding: 0;
}

.comment p:focus {
 background: #fff;
}

.emoji {
 width: 1.4em;
 height: 1.4em;
 position: relative;
 top: 0.15em;
 display: inline-block;
 background-size: contain;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: 0;
 background-image: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/124740/1f62c.svg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.ice-creme.de/js/imojify.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="comments">
 <div class="comment">
  <p contenteditable="true">
   lorem ipsum 
   <span class="emoji emoji-grimacing" title=":grimacing:"></span>
  </p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: huh that was actually the problem. Thanks

Comment: Glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery doesn't do what you're suggesting. Here's a demo that shows there are no `&nbsp;` added.

```js
$('.comments').on('mousedown', '.comment p', editComment);

function editComment(el) {
  $(this).children('span').each(function() {
    var emoji = $(this).attr('title');
    $(this).replaceWith(emoji);
  });
}
```

```css
p {
  border: 2px dashed purple;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class=comments>
  <div class=comment>
    <p>
      <span class="emoji emoji-laughing" title=":laughing:">test</span>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

More likely, the culprit is the plugin you're using. Here's another demo with some `&nbsp;` added manually, but that has `.trim()` called to eliminate whitespace padding.

```js
$('.comments').on('mousedown', '.comment p', editComment);

function editComment() {
  $(this).children('span').each(function() {
    var emoji = $(this).attr('title');
    $(this).replaceWith(emoji.trim());
  });
}
```

```css
p {
  border: 2px dashed purple;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class=comments>
  <div class=comment>
    <p>
      <span class="emoji emoji-laughing" title=":laughing:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;">test</span>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @creme: I can only respond to what you presented in the question. Your demo doesn't show the behavior you describe, and if there is such padding being added, then `.trim()` will remove it. If it doesn't, then you haven't accurately described the problem.

Comment: @creme: Your animated gif seems to show a short pause before the extra space appears.  Is that actually what happens?

Comment: no the extra space appears as soon as i hit backspace. Thats why theres a short pause

Comment: try to click at the very end of the snipped in my post and hit backspace. There will be 2 &nbsp;'s added